# Current status of the research on Universal Logic using Béziau's definition of logical structures as it is

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

In the book [Logica Universalis: Towards a General Theory of Logic](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764383534) Béziau writes (see page 14),

> **My idea was to focus on a logical structure of type $(\mathbb{S}; \vdash)$ where $\vdash$ is a relation on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{S})\times\mathbb{S}$. The important thing is that the structure of $\mathbb{S}$ is not specified**, in
>   fact, further on, any kind of structure can be put on $\mathbb{S}$, not only an algebraic structure. We are back therefore to something very close to Tarski’s original theory of consequence operator. **One important difference is that in this new definition of logical structure, no axioms are stated for the consequence relation $\vdash$, in the same way that no axioms are stated for the operators in Birkhoff’s definition of abstract algebra.** (emphasis mine)

In the book, however, several approaches are discussed to the so called field of "[Universal Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_logic)" (as Béziau calls it), however, suprisingly enough no such approaches take the definition of a logical structure as given above *at its face value*. My question hence is the following,

- Is there any paper, book etc. (preferably *in english*) that develops the theory of logical structures basing on the definition as given above? Note that, here I am *not* talking about various approaches to Universal Logic, but simply trying to know whether any comprehensive theory of logical structures has been developed by adopting Béziau's definition as it is.